# Whats with the spider helmet?

Tags: league-of-legends

Master Yi and Jax both wear some kind of interesting looking multi-lense helms. What is their purpose?

[image]

[image]

So Many EYES!!

Comment: I think Jax actually *has* seven eyes... Seven eyes, three fingers and three (two?) toes... Dunno about Yi, though.

Comment: LoL comic theory: http://th09.deviantart.net/fs71/PRE/i/2012/238/a/2/my_entry_for_the_comic_lolz_contest__3_by_melspontaneus-d5cj7m8.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Master Yi:

> **Goggles from the Inventor**
>
> The goggles Master Yi wears are a techmaturgical device that was gifted to the champion by Piltover's
> own  Heimerdinger, the Revered Inventor. Master Yi first used these
> goggles when defending his homeland from Noxus invaders in the time
> after the League has just formed and before Ionia had affiliated
> itself with the League. The goggles are fitted specifically for Master
> Yi; while someone else may wear them, they won't receive anywhere near
> the same benefit as he does himself.
>
> The one-of-a-kind goggles, known as the "Seven Lenses of Insight", allow Master Yi to see across a
> wider range of the spectrum than normal people see. They also give him
> abilities not dissimilar to that of real world binoculars and
> telescopes. The goggles are synced to Yi's own magical resonance,
> allowing him to adjust settings without the use of his hands. He
> simply thinks what he needs, and the goggles act accordingly.

Jax is more of a mystery. He has a number of strange characteristics such as two toes and three fingers. Not to mention the strange way he entered the league:

> It is seldom the case where a champion is defined by his actions after
> joining the League of Legends rather than before. Such is the case
> with Jax, for whom the argument could be made that he is the most
> prolific tournament fighter currently at the Institute of War. Before
> joining the League, Jax was an unremarkable soldier-for-hire. For
> reasons known only to the former leader of the League, High Councilor
> Reginald Ashram, Jax was put on the top of the list of candidates to
> receive a League Judgment - the interview process that either accepts
> or rejects a prospective champion. His Judgment was the quickest in
> League history, where the Doors of Acceptance glowed and slowly swung
> open as soon as it began. Jax faced no recorded Observation or
> Reflection during his Judgment.
>
> Jax proved himself to be an immediate terror in the Fields of Justice.
> The self-proclaimed Armsmaster of the League rattled off a streak of
> consecutive wins that to this day has not been matched. A number of
> summoners in the League grew concerned that the perceived objectivity
> of the League of Legends would be questioned by the presence of an
> unknown fighter who was unbeatable. For this reason, the new leader of
> the League (following Reginald Ashram's disappearance), High Councilor
> Heyward Relivash, created special restrictions for Jax to fight under.
> This was something the League had never done before, and something
> which has never been done since. The burly fighter responded by
> imposing his own special conditions; as a means of protest, he
> permitted himself to fight using only a brass lamppost. Neither the
> League's sanctions nor his own has affected his winning ways. The
> League has since rescinded its sanctions, but Jax has not; he fights
> and fights well with his trusty brass lamppost.

So I don't believe there is an official reason for him to have a multi-eyed mask on.

Although, I think the real reason is drawing pupils is hard (I swear I've seen someone from Riot make a comment to this effect, but no luck googling it). Notice a number of champions have solid colored glowing eyes.

Backgrounds from [League of Legends Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Jax/Background)

Comment: They started making champions with realistic looking pupils recently. Nearly all of the old champions have glowing pupils. I agree with your hard to draw pupil theory.